# Can AWS Athena queries be run periodically (i.e., on a schedule)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Is there any support for running Athena queries on a schedule? We want to query some data daily, and dump a summarized CSV file, but it would be best if this happened on an automated schedule.

Comment: hello , how did  u fix this problem. thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I never did solve this.

Answer (score 5):

Schedule an AWS Lambda task to kick this off, or use a cron job on one of your servers.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?  How would you get a Lambda task to kick off an Athena query?  Is the data of the query returned to the Lambda?

Comment: Is there a better way to schedule a Athena query? Can aws-glue run Athena queries on a schedule?